# Add inventory stock levels on the cart page in BigCommerce, cornerstone theme

Tags: bigcommerce, bigcommerce-stencil-cli

I would like to add **product stock inventory** value to the **cart page** (templates/components/cart/content.html) in BigCommerce cornerstone theme.

For every product item in cart, i would like to add the text - 'You have [x] item(s) in stock', with the actual value of the stock amounts in place of x.

I have been looking for a solution for 2 days but getting nowhere, any assistance will be massively appreciated, thanx.